# Completely metrizable space, complete norm

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $E$ be a normed, completely metrizable space.

Prove that the initial norm is complete.

How can I go about solving this problem?

I will be grateful for all your hints.

Thank you!

Comment: How much topology do you know. Are you familiar with Baire's theorem?

Comment: Yes, I am. How does this theorem help me here?

Comment: That depends on which version of the open mapping theorem you know. If you can find that $E$ is not meagre (of the first category) in its completion $\tilde{E}$ [for which you need that $E$ is a Baire space, which you know since it is completely metrisable], a strong enough version of the open mapping theorem shows that $E$ is its completion.

Comment: I see. We are going to have Banach's theorem about open mapping during Functional Analysis lectures, but I don't know in which form. Could you tell me how strong a version is needed to solve this problem?

Comment: The one in Rudin's book is the one needed. You can't assume surjectivity, since you don't know a priori that $E$ is complete, so you need the version with "if the image is of the second category". There are certainly other ways to prove the assertion, but that's what sprang to mind first.

Comment: Hmm, or wait. Thinking about it, I believe Rudin's version requires that the domain be complete and deduces that the codomain is complete too. So let me think about alternative ways.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've found that theorem in Rudin's Functional Analysis.

Comment: It's number 2.11 and you're right, the theorem does require the domain to be an $F$ -space (so it has to be complete)